# Why i can not run bcp utility in my sql server query?

Tags: sql-server

I'm beginner in sql server and want to save query result in text file,search on web and find any query using bcp utility,write this query on my sql server:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
  FROM [dbo].[myTABLE]" queryout c:\bcp\Tom.xls -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

but when run up query,i get this error:
[image]

how can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: Can you verify whether there is an entry in the `Path` environment variable pointing to the bin folder of SQL Server? You can find this in System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables.

Comment: @TT. hi my friend my path is this:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn

Comment: In that directory, is the `bcp.exe` file there?

Comment: If it isn't, please run the SQL Server installation and make sure `Management Tools - Basic` is installed.

Comment: @TT okay,please wait to install that

Comment: @TT ok,i install that,and bcp is there,but get that error again

Comment: Are you connecting with SSMS to a remote server? In that case, be aware that the SQL scripts are executed remotely. Verify whether the bcp utility is installed on the remote server rather than locally. Also: have you tried rebooting :)

Comment: @TT. my sql server install on my local PC.

Comment: @TT. i reboot the my server and work,thanks my friend for pay attention to my problem

Comment: I have summarized the solution as an answer. Glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `Management Tools - Basic` part of the SQL Server installation is not installed. The `bcp.exe` utility is part of `Management Tools - Basic`. Installing `Management Tools - Basic` and rebooting will solve the problem.